# How can I clone/cast image my cracked screen LG Optimus Zone 3 to Windows 10 HP

Tags: settings, lg

My screen is completely smashed 100% no visibility, I touch all over the screen and it just does random things. I just want to be able to receive sms on an app or something....

Answer (score 0):

If you know for certain that USB Debugging is enabled on the phone, try [Vysor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vysor/gidgenkbbabolejbgbpnhbimgjbffefm) for Chrome. Otherwise I don't see much luck - you'd have to interact effectively with your phone to enable USB Debugging or make other workarounds work.